# Sum Multi Dimensional array if the sub key is exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array which has more then 100 results but some of these has same sub array key. I would like to sum array element which has same key which is `[/xyx/888350]` in this example. However, I want to keep the format as it is which is two dimensional.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [/xyx/888350] => /xyx/888350
                [visitors] => 1
                [pageviews] => 2
                [uniquepageviews] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [/xyx/888350] => /xyx/888350
                [visitors] => 1
                [pageviews] => 3
                [uniquepageviews] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [/xyx/888350] => /xyx/888350
                [visitors] => 1
                [pageviews] => 2
                [uniquepageviews] => 1
            )
       [3] => Array
            (
                [/xyx/102254] => /xyx/102254
                [visitors] => 1
                [pageviews] => 2
                [uniquepageviews] => 1
            )
    )
```

I am expecting out put something like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [/xyx/888350] => /xyx/888350
            [visitors] => 2
            [pageviews] => 7
            [uniquepageviews] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [/xyx/102254] => /xyx/102254
            [visitors] => 1
            [pageviews] => 3
            [uniquepageviews] => 1
        )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of strange structure is this, where you use a variable string as the key in an associative array? How are you supposed to access those elements?

Comment: is the variable key always first in the sub-array? If not, does the variable key always begin with `/`?

Comment: Not really. I have tried few things, in_array() function and other related php functions.

Comment: Do you have any influence over the input data? Like I said, that's a really perverted way to store the key field. Is there perhaps another array that contains the list of all those keys?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just started my career as Developer. I am learning.

Comment: Did you design this structure? Try changing the first element to something like `[path] => /xyx/102265`

Comment: If I change the dynamically generated key, then how am I suppose to know which one is repeated and which one is not. If I have [path] as key as you have suggested, how am I going to sum the value based on Key.

Comment: It's the value of `$array[$i]['path']`.

Comment: If you implement @d.raev's answer, you would do `$key = $data['path']`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar @d.raev, I will remember what you have said. As time goes on, I will also help other people. As you can see, I have started answering other people's questions on topic like jQuery. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results=$service->data_ga->get("");
$stats = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($stats_results=$results->getRows()) ; $i++)
{
   $stats[]=array(
     'path'=>$stats_results[$i][1],
     'visitors'=>$stats[$i]['visitors'] + $stats_results[$i][2],
     'pageviews'=>$stats[$i]['visitors'] + $stats_results[$i][3],
     'uniquepageviews'=>$stats[$i]['visitors'] + $stats_results[$i][4]
   );
}
$result = array();
foreach($stats as $data){
     $keys = array_keys($data);
     $key = $keys[0]; //get the first key of the array a.k.a '/xyx/888350'
     if(isset($result[$key]))
     {
       //sum the values if we have this key
       $result[$key]['visitors']         += $data['visitors'];
       $result[$key]['pageviews']        += $data['pageviews'];
       $result[$key]['uniquepageviews']  += $data['uniquepageviews'];

    }else{
       $result[$key] = $data;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [path] => Array
        (
            [path] => /path/888350
            [visitors] => 3
            [pageviews] => 7
            [uniquepageviews] => 3
        )

)
```

Thanks both of you. As time goes on I will also answer questions other people have. I have just started my career. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Loop the array, and store the results in a temporary array, by using the first value as a key:

```
  $input = /*your example data here*/;
  $result = array();

  foreach($input as $data){
     $keys = array_keys($data);
     $key = $keys[0]; //get the first key of the array a.k.a '/xyx/888350'
     if(isset($result[$key])){
          //sum the values if we have this key
          $result[$key]['visitors']         += $data['visitors'];
          $result[$key]['pageviews']        += $data['pageviews'];
          $result[$key]['uniquepageviews']  += $data['uniquepageviews'];
     }else{
          $result[$key] = $data;
     }
  }

  //drop the extra keys and return a indexed array with the summed values
  return array_values($result);
```

Comment: Hi D, thanks for your time. I will implement this into my code and put result here. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if this solved your problem you can accept the answer :)